# Django admin: Get logged In users id in django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am new to django and learnign it. I am using django's Auth and i need to get the id of the logged in user at some place. I have tried :

`HttpRequest.user.id` referring to the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user) but this throws exception :

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: type object 'HttpRequest' has no attribute 'user'
```

*My code :*

```
from django.http import HttpRequest
#...some other code here..#

class Post(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     body = models.TextField('post body')
     author = models.ForeignKey(User)

     def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
          self.author = HttpRequest.user.id
          super(Post, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

*--UPDATE ---*

I have also tried :

```
from django.http import request
```

and then in save method :

```
self.author = request.user.id
```

but it gives me exception -

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Comment: `HttpRequest` is a class not object instance. You need to pass `request` or `request.user` or `request.user.id` to models `save()` method and then use it.

Comment: How can i do that can you please explain ?

Comment: You don't need to mess with the `save` method. In your view, you can get the current use using `request.user`, and assign it to the instance of your Model and then save it.

Comment: I am trying to do this for the admin site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't override the model's `save()` method, but override the admin `save_model()` method instead:

```
class Post(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        super(Post, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: Updated the question. Please check. Using `request.user` throws exception

Comment: Updated answer to admin related way.

Comment: worked. thanks .. however i think it should be `super(Post, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)` right ?

Comment: @BaDDeveloper: Yes my bad, I fixed the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

HttpRequest is a **class**, which doesn't have an `user` attribute. You need to obtain the request **object**, most likely from a view function. Then you can pass the user object, or its id to your model `save()` method:

```
def view_function(request):
     user = request.user
     # Get the object you want to save the user field to
     post = Post.objects.get(...) 
     post.user = user
     # Or post.user_id = user.id
     post.save()
     ... ...
```