# RESOLVED: Django Admin: How to display currently logged in user's ID on the display list?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am very new to Django and trying to make my first project. I find it difficult to display currently logged in user's ID on the list in Django admin model.

I found a solution of how to get the appriopriate ID thanks to Shang Wang ([Django admin: Get logged In users id in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479738/django-admin-get-logged-in-users-id-in-django/32480207#32480207?newreg=e58da89b0a2545d2bf8bacc10c3945d8))

But I don't know how to display this ID on the list, right next to Patient ID, Unit and Create time (mentioned in the code below).

My `admin.py` looks like this :

```
class GeneralAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        super(GeneralAdmin, self).save_model(request, form, obj, change)
    list_display = ('id_patient', 'unit', 'create_time')
    search_fields = ('id_patient', 'unit', 'create_time')
    readonly_fields = ('unit', 'Birth_date','create_time',)
```

Edit 2: my `models.py` file:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date, datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Unit(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Patient(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Patient ID')
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Birth_date = models.DateField()
    introducer = models.ForeignKey(User, 
        help_text = "This field will be calculated automatically", 
        blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
        #here I try to get current user's ID

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.introducer = User.username #here I get an error
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class General(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, help_text = "This field will be calculated automatically", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, help_text = "This field will be calculated automatically")
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null = True, default = datetime.now())
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.Birth_date = self.id_patient.Birth_date
        self.unit = self.id_patient.unit
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class Primary_Treatment_EBRT(models.Model):
    
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit, help_text = "This field will be calculated automatically", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Birth_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, help_text = "This field will be calculated automatically")
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null = True, default = datetime.now())
    id_patient = models.ForeignKey('Patient', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.Birth_date = self.id_patient.Birth_date
        self.unit = self.id_patient.unit
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

How to put `obj.user`'s ID into `list_display` to display it on the list like `id_patient`, `unit`, or `create_time`?

---

Problem **RESOLVED**:

My `admin.py` change:

```
class PatientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change, *args, **kwargs):
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.create_time = datetime.now()
        super(PatientAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change, *args, **kwargs)
```

My `models.py` change:

```
create_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null = True)
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, 
    null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Can you share your models.py structure, please? It will be easy to provide the exact answer then.

Comment: Sure, but I have a lot of fields in my models so I will put only few of them to keep it readable.

Comment: Your `Patient` models doesn't seem to be related to `User`? How would you associate a patient to an user?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt, I've tried to change my `Patient` model (see 'introducer' and 'def save ...'). I want to make 'introducer' field read only since I would like this field to be fullfiled automatically after clicking 'Save' and cannot be changed by the user. When I try to do this, I get an error : `Cannot assign "<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x0000022979CC0220>": "Patient.introducer" must be a "User" instance`. Can you please help me out with this?